# Unable to connect Apache Superset with Solr

Tags: kubernetes, solr, apache-superset, helm3

**Symptom:**

creating/testing database in Superset connection with this URL

```
solr://solr-master:8983/solr/my-collection
```

receiving error message

```
Could not load database driver: SolrEngineSpec
```

**Environment:**

Installed HELM Chart version: 0.6.1 on kubernetes cluster

**Approach to solve the problem**

adding sqlalchemy-solr to the bootstrapScript in values.yaml

```
#!/bin/bashrm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && pip install sqlalchemy-solr && pip install psycopg2-binary==2.9.1 && pip install redis==3.5.3 && \if [ ! -f ~/bootstrap ]; then echo "Running Superset with uid {{ .Values.runAsUser }}" > ~/bootstrap; fi
```

**Result:**

sqlalchemy-solr was curiously not installed by pip

Answer (score 1):

It was a syntax problem in the bootstrapScript. Line break must be marked with an empty row.

```
source:
 repoURL: 'https://apache.github.io/superset'
 targetRevision: 0.6.1
 helm:
  parameters:
  - name: bootstrapScript
    value: >
      #!/bin/bash

      rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

      pip install sqlalchemy-solr

      pip install psycopg2-binary==2.9.1

      pip install redis==3.5.3

      if [ ! -f ~/bootstrap ]; then echo "Running Superset with uid {{ .Values.runAsUser }}" > ~/bootstrap; fi
 chart: superset
```